# As a miner how would I put data in the 'extra' field?

Tags: blockchain, tx-extra, mining

How would I be able to put data in the extra field for say a nonce or whatever?

Comment: For the coinbase TX? Modify the code, I suppose. Not sure XMR's so-called "getblocktemplate" would allow for this, so you MAY have to make your own block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the *getblocktemplate* RPC, you can pass a *reserve_size* argument.
You will get a block template and a *reserve_offset*, and then starting at *reserve_offset* in the block template, you can put *reserve_size* bytes of whatever you want.